# I cannot get WordPress running in local mode on Windows using GAE

Tags: php, python, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

There is a nice article https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress
on how to get wordpress running under google app engine.
I am running under Windows 8 (64 Bit)
I followed the steps, installed Python and PHP used a MySQL instance I had running and added wp_user as described.
 I verified that the helloworld app runs with GAE locally.
 I verified that Mysql is running, wordpress_db exists and wp_user can connect as described in the article.
 I created wp-config.php as described.

in php,ini in my php installation I uncommented the lines 
extension=php_mysql.dll

When I run as described and hit localhost:8080 I get 
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
extension=php_mysqli.dll

I tried installing http://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/
after putting db.php in wp_content localhost:8080 says
php failure (255) with: stdout:X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20 Content-type: text/html stderr:
Stdout on the command line says
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.20
Content-type: text/html

OK I am stuck - someone has gotten this running on windows but I see no troubleshooting information and am a newbie on PHP and Wordpress which I am using for political reasons

Can anyone out there offer any help

Answer (score 0):

If you're not limited to the GAE then perhaps WAMP or XAMPP is a better bet? WAMP is fairly nice as it's a clicky-button installer with minimal knowledge required. Once it's installed, you should see a green "W" in your tray and all you need to do is point a browser to `http://localhost`.

Comment: A local deployment is a critical step to deployment on google app engine - the object of the game is to consider moving our site to gae so I would like to run in their local space before attempting an upload

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried out all kind of things, ending up uncommenting the line:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

In the `php.ini` file in my application folder. That did the trick and WordPress is now running in my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well, and after much trial and error I realized that I needed to specify the full path in php.ini

Although the tutorial only includes the line `google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, gc_enabled"` you will need to add the `extension=PATH` line where PATH is the full path to your php installation, e.g.

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, gc_enabled"
extension=C:\Users\YOUR\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll
```